# Google App Engine list of ReferenceProperties vs strings

Tags: google-app-engine

Say I have a `Club` entity and a `User` entity. A `Club` has a list of members.

Say now that I want to get all `Clubs` that a User is a part of. There are two ways to do this, each involving a list of members:

1. The list can be a list of strings which are the email addresses of the members. When I want to get the Clubs a User is a part of, I would do `clubQuery.filter('emailAddresses =', userEmail)`.
2. The list can be a list of ReferenceProperties, where each item is a reference to the User entity. So I would do `clubQuery.filter('userReferences =', user_key)`

Which would be the better option to go, and why? Or are there really no differences between the two?

Comment: Can users' email addresses change? Is it useful to have the email address of members (Without any other information) without having to do a datastore lookup? Do you ever need to look up all the members of a club? Is the key name of a User entity their email address?

Comment: Hmm I hadn't thought about the case where a user's email change. Maybe at one point in the future, but for now no. No I don't think it would be useful to have just a user's email. And if I needed to look the all the members of the club, I can just retrieve that club and get its users. And yes, the key name is their email address..

Comment: In that case I would recommend using keys - there's no good reason not to.

Comment: @NickJohnson so say I'm using the numeric ids that GAE generates as the keys (when I create a user, I just do user = User()). Would there be a difference in performance, storage, or any other internals if I were to make the list property a list of integers rather than a list of keys? Personally I'd rather deal with integers rather than keys so things are most straightforward, but it's not that important, and I'd be for keys if there was even a single advantage over integers..?

Comment: A list of ints will be smaller, yes, but contains less metadata - so if you ever have to go through anything like the HRD migration again, you'll have to write your own migration code from scratch, since the automated code won't be able to update your references for you. If you're trying to represent keys, your best option is to use keys.

Comment: @NickJohnson The HRD migration changes ID numbers? What exactly gets migrated?

Comment: No, it doesn't, but it does change App IDs, and it relies on metadata to do so. In this particular case you would have been okay during the HRD migration, but in general, storing more metadata makes it easier to do those sorts of manipulations on your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the average length of your emails, you might save some storage space by storing the emails, they keys may be longer.  Or not.

When you do a datastore get by key, you can have a strongly consistent read, rather than the eventually consistent result you get from the filter operation.  If you store the keys, you have the option of doing this when necessary.

It sounds like you have a third option, which is to use the email address as the key; you'll get the best of both worlds that way.

**Edit** I guess I wasn't really answering your question.  Here's a better answer.

- Option 1 may save you storage space and thus a bit of cost.  It's small though, maybe insignificant.
- Option 2 makes it easier to write code on the Club side because you get automatic dereferencing.
- It doesn't make a big difference on how you query what Clubs a user is part of.
- If you use my suggestion for email as a key, it could allow you fetch User entities in a consistent matter, which is a benefit you didn't ask for.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on the third option? Use email addresses as the keys where?

Comment: When you create a User object, use the email address as the key: u = User(key_name="user@server.com").  It's easy to recreate they key given the email address later.  See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass.

Comment: Ya but how does this help in finding which clubs a user belongs to?

Comment: It stays the same you can filter by __key__ = email address.

Comment: Please note that there are 2 downsides if you use email address as the key. 1 The string form of the key can be easily decoded to recover the original entity's kind and e-mail addresses. 2 It will become hard(or at least cumbersome) when users change their e-mail addresses.

Comment: @TakashiMatsuo what do you think would be a better option for the key?